# How to safely pass an array as parameter in swift

Tags: swift

Hi this is my first question posted here. I have a class which updates an array from a stream of audio samples which I periodically need to process within another class. This is the code that updates the array and removes the oldest element when it reaches a maximum size:

```
public func update(sample: Sample) {
    lastPeak = abs(sample.val) > abs(lastPeak) ? sample.val : lastPeak
    if let last = lastSample {
      if last.val * sample.val < 0 && abs(lastPeak) > minPeakSize { // this is a zero crossing
        let offset = Double(sample.index) + Double(round((sample.val/(last.val - sample.val)) * 100) / 100)
                
        let crossing = ZeroCrossing(
          index: sample.index,
          previousPeak: lastPeak,
          indexWithOffset: offset
        )
        
        self.crossings.array.append(crossing) \\ <-- ARRAY UPDATE
        
        lastPeak = 0
        while crossings.array.count > crossingsMaxSize {
          crossings.array.remove(at: 0) \\ <--ARRAY RESIZE
        }
      }
    }
    lastSample = sample
```

I then pass the array to a method within a separate class and occasionally get an index out of range error.

```
    mutating func run(crossings: Crossings, octave: Int = 2) -> CorrelationResult? {
    var result: CorrelationResult? = nil
    if crossings.array.count > 4 { 

      var lastIndex: UInt = 0
      if let lastCrossing = crossings.array.last {
        lastIndex = lastCrossing.index
      }
      var startPoint = 0
      var completeSet = false
      
      for (i, crossing) in crossings.array.reversed().enumerated() { \\ <-- INDEX OUT OF RANGE

        if lastIndex > crossing.index {
          if lastIndex - crossing.index > windowSizeForOctave[octave] && crossing.previousPeak < 0 {
            startPoint = crossings.array.count - i
            completeSet = true
            break
          }
        }
      }
```

The array is wrapped within a struct

```
struct Crossings {
  var locked = false
  var array = [ZeroCrossing]()
}
struct ZeroCrossing {
  var index: UInt
  let previousPeak: Float
  let indexWithOffset: Double
}
```

When the error occurs the array contains 500 elements and i = 0. Is there a safe way to pass arrays between classes (and I assume threads) without blocking updates to the original array?

Comment: I believe you might have already tried many different approaches, but I hope that these couple of tips might still help. Its possible that another process is changing the `crossings` array while the mutating function `run()` is running? You can try to debug by adding a `didSet { print(array.count) }` observer in the property `array` of the struct `Crossings`, see what it tells you.

Comment: @HunterLion - thanks for the suggestions. The originating class constantly updates the array but the 'copy' passed to the run function is never mutated. The didSet observer counts up until it reaches crossingsMaxSize (500) and alternates between 501 & 500 as a new element is added and the oldest removed. I think what I'm looking for is a way to force a physical copy of the array in memory that can be passed to the run function.